# Access VBA SQL Complie Error: Type Mismatch

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

This following bit of code is placed in the `On Load` event of a form:

```vb
Dim LAOQWeekdaySQL As String
Dim LAOQWeekday As QueryDef
Dim EnqIDTest As String
EnqIDTest = Me.txt_EnquiryID.Value

LAOQWeekdaySQL = "SELECT tbl_Costing_Labour.EnquiryID, tbl_Costing_Labour.PhaseLabour, tbl_Costing_Labour.TotalPhaseLabourHours " & _
                 "FROM tbl_Costing_Labour " & _
                 "WHERE (((tbl_Costing_Labour.EnquiryID)= " & EnqIDTest & ") AND ((tbl_Costing_Labour.PhaseLabour) Like ""*weekday*""));"

Set LAOQWeekday = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("LAOQWeekdayQRY").SQL = LAOQWeekdaySQL

Me.txt_LAOQ_Weekday.Value = DSum("TotalPhaseLabourHours", "LAOQWeekdayQRY")
```

Essentially it returns records matching the Inquiry Number and sums the final column in the query and outputs it to a textbox on the form.

However, when I got run the form it gives me a

> compile error: type mismatch

Prior to this I did try and use a temporary query but then the Dsum has no name to reference when performing its function so I changed it `.CreateQueryDef`, which work fine the first time. Thereafter, obviously, it threw an error saying the query already exists so I went down the route of `.QueryDefs` to update the SQL instead and now I get the mismatch error.

I cannot see anything obvious, what am I missing here?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: This line has 2 equal signs in it: `Set LAOQWeekday = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("LAOQWeekdayQRY").SQL = LAOQWeekdaySQL` What are you expecting that to do?

Comment: I don't understand why you are using a predefined query in such a way. as @braX said, your first compile error is trying to set LAOQWeekday to an object reference and trying to modify the object at the same time. You need to first set the reference, and then modify the object.

Comment: Absolutely right, an oversight on my part. I've changed it and it works as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line evaluates to a Boolean:

```vb
Set LAOQWeekday = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("LAOQWeekdayQRY").SQL = LAOQWeekdaySQL
```

Try changing it to this:

```vb
Set LAOQWeekday = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("LAOQWeekdayQRY")
LAOQWeekday.SQL = LAOQWeekdaySQL
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response, I am please to say that worked. Sorry if this was a silly question you have been a big help!